# Python. Подзначение словаря

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, словари

Я получаю словарь с информацией. Вот отрывок кода:

```
{
"id": 241623849,
"first_name": "Екатерина",
"last_name": "Миглан",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true,
"city": {
"id": 244,
"title": "Витебск"
}
```

Вот таким образом я получаю параметр город(по фамилии):

```
dv = {item.get('last_name'): item.get('city') for item in ju['profiles']}
```

Это работает, но выдаёт 2 значения: id и title, подскажите как заставить выудить именно title, без id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать метод `get` возвращёнyого словаря

```
{item.get('last_name'): item.get('city').get('title') for item in ju['profiles'] if 'city' in item}
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Это значит, что элемента с ключом `city` в словаре нет.

Comment: City есть, ведь из него мне приходят подпункты title и id

Comment: Видать есть не у всех `profiles`. Дополнил ответ, проверьте.